# Conditionally allow click Submit button

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In form I have a field which should take filename (after browsing file), and button submit. After click submit file should load to server. And it's working ok. But if I haven't selected any file (e.g. field is empty) - clicking cause exception, because nothing to load.

And yeap, hello from newbie in mvc and web technology.

How to prevent this behavior? For example how make some pop-up message after clicking sumbit, that 'input is empty'?

```
<form asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="Home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label for="file">Xml file</label>
            <div data-width="85%" class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input id="file" name="Files" type="file" accept=".xml" style="display: none;">Browse&hellip;
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Upload" />
        </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add some validation code (in both client and server if you like, but definitely in the server) to check the values of the fields in your model before you process them. It's a fairly standard thing, you should be able to read about it online

Comment: Use a view model and add a `[Required]` attribute to a `HttpPostedFileBase` property and strong bind to it using a `HtmlHelper` methods and implement mvc's client side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using javascript and data annotations, something like (use as orientation):

```
$(input).click(function(event)
{
    ...
    if($(input).files.length == 0){
        $(input).addClass("disabled");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    ...
});
```

Also use DataAnnotations at your viewmodel. If you use the `[Required]`-Attribute you can´t submit the form without a file, for example.

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is lazy and a javascript walk around, and will become tedious as soon as you have more than 1 input field.

Following the MVC pattern which stands for Model - View - Controller.

You need a Model which is your data collected from the view and is then manipulated inside the controller, in your case this is a file.

So your Model should look something like this:

```
public class MyModelName {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display a custom error message when the field is not filled out, leave this option out for default error message")]
     public IFormFile MyFileName { get; set; } 
}
```

To be able to use `MyModelName` inside a View (Let's call it `MyView` and it get's and posts to a `MyView` action inside a controller), you have to make the View aware of it. This is done by including `@model MyModelName` at the top of the View file (case sensitive). When the View is aware of the model, to refer to it use `@Model` and that will bring up the object.

Now for your form instead of manual adding attributes like `name` and `type` to the input field asp helpers are used.

So instead of:

`<input id="file" name="Files" type="file" accept=".xml" style="display: none;">`

Write it like so:

`<input id="file" asp-for="@Model.MyFileName">`

Look up what is generated using the Browser developer tools, you will see all sorts of attributes added to the input field automatically.

Anywhere on the page add a space for the validation message (Generally below the input field):

`<span asp-validation-for="@Model.MyFileName"></span>`

At this point you have server side validation which you can use by invoking `ModelState.IsValid` like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyView(MyModelName model){
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
         //proceed to do whatever with the file
    return View(model); //return the model with the validation errors
}
```

So server side validation means that before you can see the error messages in the browser but the site will have to make a round trip to the back-end.

To validate without having to make a trip to the server, you include partial validation scripts inside the view, it's provided by the default Microsoft templates. At the bottom of `MyView.cshtml` include (You will need the default jquery library for this):

```
@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Once you are at this stage you have client side validation, and the form will not be submitted unless all the validation requirements have been met.

If you further want to manipulate validation, the validation scripts you added in the partial provide a function `valid()`

which can be used like so:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    //stop the form from being submitted
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).valid()) {
        //do stuff if form is valid
    }
    //do stuff if form is not valid
})
```

More on model [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I answered that data annotations should be used too - the js approach only gives users additional visual feedback, by disabling the button.